# Why do I get a validation error when trying to disable past dates in datepicker?

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I have a [reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) that uses [ng-bootstrap's datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview) for an optional date field and I'm trying to disable past dates by setting `minDate` to the current date.

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" [minDate]="ngdate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" formControlName="startDate" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar fa fa-calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
ngdate: NgbDateStruct = {
    year: new Date().getFullYear(),
    month: new Date().getMonth() + 1,
    day: new Date().getDate()
};

this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    startDate: ['']
});
```

When I enter a date, this works correcly and all the dates before today are correctly disabled. The problem is that when I submit the form without entering a date, it's invalid with the status `errors.ngbdate`.

I think this happens because my date field starts out blank (because it's a reactive form) and is not getting initialized.

How can I disable past dates while preventing this validation error from occurring when no date is entered by the user?

Comment: I figured it out. Setting the StartDate =null solve the problem. Earlier, setting it to startDate =' ' actually assigning it blank values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Mr. Jay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458119/ng-bootstrap-setting-mindate-to-current-date-causing-validation-error-solved#comment97635923_55458119), this can be solved by changing `startDate: ['']` to `startDate: null`.